# Vectors - More Elegance?

Tags: c++, vector

I am working with vectors and I am initialising them like so:

```
vector<int> values;

values.push_back(1);
values.push_back(2);
values.push_back(8);
values.push_back(12);
values.push_back(32);
values.push_back(43);
values.push_back(23);
values.push_back(234);
values.push_back(7);
values.push_back(1);
```

Is there a way, to push_back these elements in a way that is array-like? Like this:

```
    int numbers[2] = {1, 2};
```

The vector method takes up too many lines, IMO!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In C++11 you can use brace initialization with any container.

```
std::vector <int> v = {1, 2, 8, 12, 32 ...};
```

In C++03 you can do this

```
const int arr[] = {1, 2, 8, 12, 32 ... };
const int size = sizeof arr / sizeof arr[0];
std::vector<int> v(arr, arr + size);
```

or use [boost assign](http://www.boost.org/libs/assign/).

```
#include <boost/assign.hpp>
using namespace boost::assign;
///...
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    v += 1, 2, 8, 12, 32;
}
```

Comment: Ah, Boost. So often I forget your marvels.

Comment: Good list, I think in order of preferance I would go with 1, 3, 2 :)

Comment: @111111: I quite dislike the abuse of the operators in that particular boost library.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas, I think it's pretty clear what that code does. I wouldn't call it misuse when it's useful, clear, and unambiguous.

Comment: @David Rodríguez - dribeas I think it was well justified at the time it made up for a missing language feature, which has subsequently been added, anf if your are stuck with C++03 it still makes perfect sense.

Comment: @chris: Not to mention that it's simply adorable! :)

Comment: Don't even mention the weird [piping syntax](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/introduction.html) - this is C++, not bash!

Comment: @sftrabbit, I always found that one interesting, but it is pretty unique and self-explanatory as well.

Comment: @chris: Is it? `std::vector<int> v; v += 1,(2,3),4;` or `int x = 0; v+= ++x, ++x, ++x;` What is the outcome of those two operations?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: 1) 1, 3, 4 3) UB, but this thing can happen all the time all over C++... I still like the library :)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas, Yes, you should understand the risks of UB and the infamous comma operator, but in the general case, it's pretty clean.

Comment: @ildjarn: Actually if it were non-overloaded `operator ,` it would be a sequence point and thus no UB. In case of overloaded operator it's simply a function call with no specific order of evaluation of operands making it actually UB, just as in case of f(x++, x++);

Comment: @Armen : My mistake, footnote 83 cleared things up succinctly for me. Thanks.

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan: Except that if `v` is an `int` then `v += ++x,++x,++x;` is perfectly defined. By means of overloading the operator the semantics of code that looks exactly the same does not behave the same. This is the same reason why you should not overload `operator||` or `operator&&`, as the overloaded operator will not have the same semantics as the built-in operators. If you cannot provide the same behavior as the built-in operator, you should avoid overloading it.

Answer (score 4):

There is indeed a way to do this, provided you have your hands on a C++11 compiler:

```
std::vector<int> values = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

This is known as an initializater list. `std::vector` has a [constructor that takes an initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) (see declaration 7) to initialise its elements.

Comment: Thank you. I seem to not have a C++11 compiler.

Comment: @Phorce, If you have the option of using one, I'd definitely go for it. Which do you use?

Comment: @Phorce Which compiler are you using? If `g++`, use the `-std=c++0x` flag to compile C++11 code. VC++ 2010 and onwards support initializer lists by default.

Comment: @chris Don't shout/hate :P I'm using g++ to compile the code.

Comment: Or `-std=c++11` if your version of GCC supports it. I think it has a couple extra things over `-std=c++0x`. @Phorce, you can find a pretty recent distro [here](http://nuwen.net/mingw.html) if you use MinGW with it.

Comment: @chris Thank you. Basically, when I try using "-std=c++0x" or "-std=c++11" it throws an error: "cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"" does that mean I do not have C++ 11 installed and should download it?

Comment: sftrabbit : VC++ does not yet support initializer lists at all, even in 2012 RTM. @Phorce : it sounds like you have a very old version of GCC. What version are you using?

Comment: @Phorce, Yeah, your version of GCC must be pretty old then. Like I said, if you're on Windows, the link is pretty good. It comes with Boost and some other stuff as well.

Comment: @ildjarn, Technically [this thing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/11/02/visual-c-c-11-and-the-future-of-c.aspx) supports them, but the libraries haven't been updated along with the compiler, so it still won't work with this. Hopefully the other parts don't take too long and we'll see a new compiler release soon :)

Comment: @chris : Unfortunately the license on that CTP is a bit draconian. :-[ I'm certainly looking forward to the proper release though!

Answer (score 3):

In C++11, you can do it the same way you do with arrays. `std::vector` has a constructor that takes a `std::initializer_list<T>`, which allows it to initialize itself from the list.

In C++03, you can use a temporary array:

```
int tempValues[] = {1,2,8,12,32,43,23,234,7,1};
std::vector<int> values(tempValues, tempValues + sizeof tempValues / sizeof tempValues[0]);
```